# Button that close from 1 and opens form 2

Tags: c#, .net, forms

so what i want is when you press the button you open form 2 where my game is. the button wich is at form 1 is going to be my main menu for the game, you click it and it opens the game and closes the menu (if it is possible to do this with out having 2 forms and just using 1 do share how i can do this)

Form 1

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication3
{
    public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Form 2

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Spill
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Form

        {
        Random _random;


        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            _random = new Random();
        }

        private void MainWindow_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            Size s = new System.Drawing.Size(800, 600);
            this.ClientSize = s; 
            this.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.FixedSingle;
        }

        private void MainWindow_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            {
                if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Left)
                {
                    Player.Left -= 20;
                }

                if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Right)
                {
                    Player.Left += 20;
                }

            }
        }

        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int z = _random.Next(0, 10);
            int x = _random.Next(0, 20);
            int y = _random.Next(0, 30);
            LargeEnemy.Left += z;
            MediumEnemy.Left += x;
            SmallEnemy.Left += y;

        }

        private void newGameToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Application.Restart();
        }

        private void quitGameToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
             Application.Exit();
        }

        private void LargeEnemy_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's very simple:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
System.Data;
System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
System.Text;
System.Threading.Tasks;
System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication3
{
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         //hide the current winform
         this.Hide();
         //create game  winform
         WindowsFormsApplication1 frmGame = new WindowsFormsApplication1();
         //show the game winform
         frmGame.ShowDialog();
         //when the game winform closes show again the menu 
         this.Show();
    }
}
}
```

and in the second form in this functions set them like this

```
    private void newGameToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }

    private void quitGameToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a very simple example using a form manager to handle a single instance.  This way both forms stay live and you are just updating the visibility.

You will want to close both forms correctly to close the application.

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
            {

                static class FormManager
                {
                    public static Form1 Game = new Form1();
                    public static Form2 Menu = new Form2();

                }

                /// <summary>
                /// The main entry point for the application.
                /// </summary>
                [STAThread]
                static void Main()
                {
                    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
                    Application.Run(FormManager.Game);
                }




                public partial class Form1 : Form
                {
                    private void btn_Menu_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
                    {
                        FormManager.Game.Hide();
                        FormManager.Menu.Show();
                    }
                }

                public partial class Form2 : Form
                {

                    private void btn_Close_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
                    {
                        FormManager.Menu.Hide();
                        FormManager.Game.Show();
                    }
                }


            }
```